# Selecting multiple mails in Outlook for Python script

Tags: python, python-2.7, outlook

I have got a simple Python 2.7 script which takes a selected email from Outlook and  then extracts some info from it and do the stuff. I'd like to improve my script to allow it to process multiple emails at once. My script needs to recognize that more than 1 emails are selected and then process each of these.

```py
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
selection = outlook.ActiveExplorer().Selection
num_items = selection.Count
subject = selection.Item(1).Subject
domain = selection.Item(1).SenderEmailAddress
```

and so on...

I believe that I should change something with the first two lines so it'll take all the selected emails instead of just one and then put some loops, but I have no idea how to include this multiselection into the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you just need to iterate over all selected items in Outlook. The `Selection` property of the `Explorer` class returns a [Selection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.selection) object that contains the item or items that are selected in the explorer window. For example, here is the VBA code which iterates through all items selected in Outlook:

```
Sub GetSelectedItems()  
 Dim myOlExp As Outlook.Explorer  
 Dim myOlSel As Outlook.Selection  
 Dim mySender As Outlook.AddressEntry  
 Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem  
 Dim oAppt As Outlook.AppointmentItem  
 Dim oPA As Outlook.PropertyAccessor  
 Dim strSenderID As String  
 Const PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_ENTRYID As String = _  
 "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x00410102"  
 Dim MsgTxt As String  
 Dim x As Long  

 MsgTxt = "Senders of selected items:"  
 Set myOlExp = Application.ActiveExplorer  
 Set myOlSel = myOlExp.Selection  

 For x = 1 To myOlSel.Count
  If myOlSel.Item(x).Class = OlObjectClass.olMail Then  
   ' For mail item, use the SenderName property. 
   Set oMail = myOlSel.Item(x)  
   MsgTxt = MsgTxt & oMail.SenderName & ";"  
  ElseIf myOlSel.Item(x).Class = OlObjectClass.olAppointment Then  
   ' For appointment item, use the Organizer property.  
   Set oAppt = myOlSel.Item(x)  
   MsgTxt = MsgTxt & oAppt.Organizer & ";"  
  Else  
   ' For other items, use the property accessor to get the sender ID,  
   ' then get the address entry to display the sender name.  
   Set oPA = myOlSel.Item(x).PropertyAccessor  
   strSenderID = oPA.GetProperty(PR_SENT_REPRESENTING_ENTRYID)  
   Set mySender = Application.Session.GetAddressEntryFromID(strSenderID)  
   MsgTxt = MsgTxt & mySender.Name & ";"  
  End If  
 Next x  
 Debug.Print MsgTxt  
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! I see, how it should be done.

```py
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
selection = outlook.ActiveExplorer().Selection
num_items = selection.Count

i = 1

for x in selection:
    subject = selection.Item(i).Subject
    domain = selection.Item(i).SenderEmailAddress
    #do more staff here
    i = i + 1
    if i <= num_items: 
        continue
    else: 
        break
```